# IntentService GCMIntent Service exceptions when using navigation drawer app

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-cloud-messaging

I tried to receive notifications from PushBots on a navigation drawer app has `MainActivity` and multiple fragments....I wrote this code in `HomeFragment`

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
                    false);
    diviceReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(getActivity());

                }
            });
}
```

and here is my manifest file

```
 <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive dataf message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity

            android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MESSAGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
    android:name="com.pushbots.google.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="info.androidhive.slidingmenu" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.DefaultPushHandler" />
<service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />

    </application>
```

I success to register my device on `PushBots`...**BUT** when I send a notification, application stopped and has following error:

```
05-21 12:14:07.613: E/AndroidRuntime(12087): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-1037294394366-1]
05-21 12:14:07.613: E/AndroidRuntime(12087): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat
```

what's Wrong?

Comment: Whats your package name?

Comment: "info.androidhive.slidingmenu"

Comment: Then what is "com.pushbots.push" ?

Answer (score 0):

Change In Menifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
          android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
       <category android:name="YOUR PACKAGE NAME"/>
     </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Comment: what do you change?? I don't see any changes

Comment: Check properly. I have changed  android:name="com.pushbots.google.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" line.

Comment: dont work.....when I make project have one activity (MainActivity) evry thing works fine...But here when I have multiple fragments I have this error

Answer (score 0):

Your project cannot find `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`. Download the Android Support Library and Android Support Repository through the SDK Manager and import NotificationCompat in your class.

As a side note, I see that you use a 3rd party library (PushBots). Just wanted to let you know that their example uses deprecated material. You do not need `<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>`.